# pass vector of string values to a macro problem

Tags: c++, macros

I try to access the variables of a class through names in a vector.
here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define DECLARE(X, i) #X->i

class dut{
public:
    int clock;
    double reset;
    dut(int a, int b){
        this->clock = a;
        this->reset = b;
  }
    ~dut();
};


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    dut *d = new dut(4, 5);
    std::vector<std::string>var;
    var.push_back("clock");
    var.push_back("reset");
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator it;
    for(it = var.begin(); it != var.end(); ++it){
        std::cout << DECLARE(d, *it) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I expect to see 4 and 5 in the output. But the error I get every time I compile is :

```
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘*’ token
   25 |   std::cout << DECLARE(d, *it) << std::endl;
```

Can anybody please help me?

I tried to access the variables of a class via names stored in a vector.

But the problem is how to pass string variable to a macro.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? What is the actual and underlying problem the macro is supposed to solve? Your use of the macro just don't make any sense, your invocation of it will result in the code `"d"->*it`.

Comment: What you think this `#X` do in  `#define DECLARE(X, i) #X->i`?

Comment: `DECLARE(d, *it)` becomes `"d"-> *it`.  Is that what you want?  Preprocessor macros are generally avoided for this reason -- the code you see is not the code the compiler sees.

Comment: There is not metadata/reflection in C++. There are some library solution to solve this, but this depends on exactly why you need this. Do you use some advanced libraries/frameworks, like boost, Qt, .... .

Comment: C++ does not have the reflection capabilities you are looking for (yet). If you search this site for "C++ reflection" you can find some answers, but you should ask yourself what you hope to gain from this?

Comment: This is very much an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Please ask about the real, underlying and actual problem directly, instead of ask us for help with your solution to the unknown (for us) problem. There might be different solutions that we can help with.

Comment: Yes this is clearly XY problem based on comment under my answer: "But my goal is to access the elements of dut class via the names which are stored in vector var. "

Comment: A further complication is that you would end up with an expression that has different types in different iterations of the loop, which is impossible.

Comment: when working with macros you should look at the output of the preprocessor, the code that the compiler will compile. With gcc its `-E`. However, the macro is somewhat irrelevant to begin with, because it does not really help with what you actually want to do (whatever that is)

Comment: `using dup = std::map<std::string, std::variant<int, double>>;` or wrapper around that?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I think I know that you want to do, print the `d->clock` and `d->reset` values, am I right?

Then I suggest you overload the `<<` operator to print `dut` objects.

Like

```
std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream& os, dut const& d)
{
    return os << d.clock << '\n' << d.reset;
}
```

Use it like you would output anything else:

```
std::cout << *d << '\n';
```

---

On another note, there's no need to use pointers and dynamic allocation for the `dut` object `d`.

Comment: Hi there. thanks for your answer. you think correct. I'm trying to print d->clock and d->reset. But the thing is that, clock and reset come from another data structure. 

I have a vector of names. And I want to see which names from the vector does the dut class have, and print them.

Comment: @BenEslami Then you need some kind of map, to map from the name to the member. So it's back almost to my original comment, what is the original, underlying and actual problem you need to solve? Why do you have a vector of member names? Where does this vector come from? What is the problem this vector is supposed to solve? And even if the structure is not one you have made yourself, you can still create functions using the structure, including overloading the `<<` operator for the structure.

Answer (score 2):

If you like just print all fields of `struct` there is nice [boost::pfr library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/boost_pfr.html) which can do this:

```cpp
#include <boost/pfr.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class dut {
public:
    int clock;
    double reset;
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    dut d { 4, 5.433 };

    boost::pfr::for_each_field(
        d, [](const auto& field) { std::cout << field << '\n'; });

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nEx683aG1

There are some limitation for this library, like there is no name of field.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But my goal is to access the elements of dut class via the names which are stored in vector var.  I have a vector of names. And I want to see which names from the vector does the dut class have, and print them.

Comment: then use [boost::describe](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/describe/doc/html/describe.html#classes). Not so clean as `boost::pfr` but has all functionality you need.

Comment: And please edit your question to clearly state your goal, so other/new answers could be better.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not easy in current C++. Maybe when in few years we will have [reflection](https://gracicot.github.io/reflection/2018/04/03/reflection-present.html) in C++  - then it will be easy doable.

You simply cannot easily get object member field having only its runtime name.

But still, there are some options on the table, but most probably needs some redesign of your project.

1. Use tuple of [pointers to members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access)

```
#include <tuple>

struct A { int foo; char bar; };
int main() {
   A a{1, 'a'};
   std::tuple var{&A::foo, &A::bar};
   // use var to get/print selected members
   std::apply([&a](auto ...field){ (std::cout << ... << field); }, var);
}
// prints: 1a
```

2. Design your own mapping from string to some access to member, use std::function:

```
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <variant> // or <any> if this mechanism will need to work for any type

using field_types = std::variant<int, char>; // more types if needed

using access_type = std::function<field_types(const A&)>;
std::map<std::string, access_type> field_mapping{
   {"foo", [](const A& a) { return a.foo; }},
   {"bar", [](const A& a) { return a.bar; }},
};

int main() {
   A a{1, 'a'};
   std::vector<std::string> var{"foo", "bar"};
   for (auto&& s : var)
   {
       auto field = field_mapping[s](a);
       std::visit([](auto value) { std::cout << value; }, field);
   }
}
```